# Understanding and comparing execution times of various computations

Tags: r, microbenchmark

1. In the first comparison, `r sqrt(5)^2`has better mean timing compared to `r sqrt(5^2)`. Why is this happening?
2. In the second comparison the above is reversed. I have tried it with more number of iterations (times).
   Finding it difficult to understand what is going on.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sqrt(5)^2,sqrt(5^2), times = 1e3)
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>       expr min  lq    mean median  uq   max neval cld
#>  sqrt(5)^2 144 151 210.705    162 169  6304  1000  a 
#>  sqrt(5^2) 148 157 269.604    169 226 25936  1000   b
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sqrt(5)^2,sqrt(5^2), log(exp(5)), times = 1e3)
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>         expr min  lq    mean median  uq  max neval cld
#>    sqrt(5)^2 145 168 193.956    180 184 3059  1000   a
#>    sqrt(5^2) 149 159 189.753    170 176 3778  1000   a
#>  log(exp(5)) 132 147 183.599    154 166 8062  1000   a
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @Onyambu interesting `sqrt(x) takes less time compared to sqrt(y) where y>x`, I couldn't confirm this, tried with input: `set.seed(1); x <- sample(1:10, 10000, replace = TRUE); y <- sample(101:110, 10000, replace = TRUE)`, median values are actually smaller for bigger numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't make much sense to compare with one input - 5. Try longer vector. We can see medians are consistent.

```
x <- 1:10000

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sqrt(x)^2, sqrt(x^2), times = 10000)
# Unit: microseconds
#       expr  min   lq     mean median   uq     max neval cld
#  sqrt(x)^2 29.0 51.6 95.77408   54.9 58.3 79210.8 10000  a 
#  sqrt(x^2) 35.4 47.0 61.64323   48.8 52.0  8017.2 10000   b

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sqrt(x)^2, sqrt(x^2), log(exp(x)), times = 10000)
# Unit: microseconds
#         expr   min     lq      mean median    uq     max neval cld
#    sqrt(x)^2  28.2  52.25 100.85237   56.1  60.4 80131.9 10000  a 
#    sqrt(x^2)  35.4  47.70  57.88721   49.7  53.5  4441.1 10000  a 
#  log(exp(x)) 162.1 196.90 262.39865  202.4 220.5 83254.2 10000   b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not sufficient to only look at the mean. The mean is prone to outliers, which you definitely have when you look at the max values. Here you see that you always have an extremely large value for just one of the two expression. This ultimately skews the mean.

The median is more stable in regard to outliers. Like, @zx8754 said: the values are more consistent.